# What's the equivalent of Deferred for repeated events?

Tags: python, events, twisted, deferred

A Deferred is a pretty wonderful abstraction for a deferred task. I'd like to set something up that is equally elegant for repeated events, e.g. my protocol receives a message and I want different parts of my code to register their callbacks to be called when that message is received. A deferred is inappropriate, here. What is appropriate, in the twisted world?

Comment: You appear to describe an "[observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)". I'm not expert in Python, but Google gives plenty of promising results for "python observer pattern".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tubes](http://tm.tl/1956).  They're [not done yet](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/branches/tubes-1956-3), but you can read some in-development [docs](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/branches/tubes-1956-3/doc/core/howto/tube.xhtml) and [some](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/branches/tubes-1956-3/doc/core/howto/listings/tubes) [examples](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/branches/tubes-1956-3/doc/core/examples/amptube.py).

Comment: So it's safe to say that twisted.internet will be a series of tubes?

Comment: this actually sort of reminds me of [Flapjax](http://www.flapjax-lang.org/) , might be worth taking a look, it's quite the interesting project